Pyautogui in not click in some games, but sometimes it works
I am playing a game call Seal Online Blades of Destiny, and I run it as window mode, I write a Pyautogui program with vscode, there is click event that click in game's position, run it as admin, but maybe 1000 times it will success one time, I mean, when I run the program, it usually not click in the game, it click behind of it, I restart the program over and over again, it will success sometimes, but it take to much times, does any know why is that?
I am just using
pydirectinput.moveto(x, y) 
pydirectinput.mouseDown()
time.sleep(0.5)
pydirectinput.mouseUp()

x y is in game window

Some games bypass the Windows input system specifically to deter cheaters like this.

but sometimes it work, I just want to understand why it work and keep it, let it work every stable

How do you know it clicks "behind" it?  What application is behind?  How did you get x and y?

behind is like desktop, because when I move the mouse, it still go to the x y that I point, but not click in game, because I minmized the game, then the mouse will work fine with other window

My guess is this is just anti-cheat coding on their part.  Maybe they shift the focus quickly.

but when I use the window.getactivewindow, it is the game window, and i move the mouse is in the game too, but the script not handle it in game window
